# Viewing all SQL Tables in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce, datareader, dataadapter

I have a `DataGridView` that loads table names. Get tables is called in the constructor. I have 9 tables stored in the .sdf database. When it loads I have all tables listed at least 81 times. How can I show one of each table name? I'm using *SqlCe 3.5* and *C# 2010 Express*. Here is my code :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void getTables(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    string strConnect = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConnect))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", con))
        {
            using (SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = com;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are mixing and combining two things. To retrieve data, you can use a `DataAdapter` **OR** a `DataReader`, not each of them. Here you only need the `DataAdapter` to fill the table.

```
private void getTables(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    string strConnect = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\LWADataBase.sdf";
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConnect)) {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", con)) {
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter()) {
                da.SelectCommand = com;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```